# OpenCV2.4.2: How do I rebuild?

Tags: opencv, windows-xp

I was successful in installing MINGW32 and CMake and rebuilt OpenCV 2.3.2 (the superpak). But V2.4.2 is not the superpak and doesn't have all the files that V2.3.1 has. My attempt to rebuild was very short (seconds rather than 20 minutes). This is Win XP Pro SP3.

The OpenCV wiki and various guides don't work because the V2.4.2 package is very different. The Yahoo OpenCV group does not respond. My guess is they don't know.

Can I/Do I rebuild V2.4.2, and if so how?

Answer (score 2):

Same way you build any other version.

Run cmake-gui, configure, generate then build the resulting .sln

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B_VS2010_CMake

Comment: I'm building for Code::Blocks and not VS2010. But that should make no difference. I've also followed the process here (http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide, step 2). As I said, the process works with V2.3.1, but V2.4.2 does not have the same make files, and it doesn't generate the separate DLLs for debug and release modes. This is typical: newer packages tend to make installation guides obsolete. So the question is what do I do with them?

Comment: are you building from src? Haven't used code::blocks but mingw is one of the options in cmake the result should be a makefile

Comment: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/CodeBlocks says its talking about V2.4.2, but the file names it uses are for V2.0.0 and the files such as cxcore*d.lib don't exist in the downloaded package.

Comment: Nope, not building from source, as far as I know. But I've never read CMAke files, so I don't know.

Comment: @louarnold - you mean build your OWN app not opencv? The libs in 2.4.2 are renamed slightly opencv_"MODULE"242.lib and 242d.lib for debug.

Comment: No, its OpenCV2.4.2 I attempted to rebuild. Those libs are for VC++ (vc9/vc10; x86/x64). After the attempt with CMake to rebuild MingW there should have been a version for that compiler in subfolders "mingw" if it follows the V2.3.2 pattern.

Comment: Correction: "rebuild MingW" -> "rebuild with MinGW"